# How to login to website without a page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am using twitter bootstrap modal window for registration form. when I click on "Register" after filling the form, it sends data to mysql and session begins.

how to ensure that one remains at same webpage from which he has clicked "register" link.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){
      var str = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax(
         {
         type: "POST",
         url:"register_process.php",
         data: str,
         success:function(result)
                {
                $("#div1").html(result);
                }
          });
      return false;
       });
   });
</script>


</head>
<body>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SIGN UP</a>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

<div id="contact_form">  
<form id="ajax-contact-form" name="contact" action=""> 
<fieldset>
    <div class="field_container">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="cust_firstname" id="firstname"  maxlength="50" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />



<div class="field_container">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="cust_lastname" id="lastname" maxlength="50" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />


<div class="sex_check" >
<input type="radio" name="cust_sex" type="radio" value="M" /> Male
<input type="radio" name="cust_sex" type="radio" value="F" /> Female


<hr class="line_break">

<div class="field_container">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="cust_email" id="email"  maxlength="100" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />



<div class="field_container">Password:</label>
<input type='password' name='cust_password' id='password'  maxlength="12" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />



<div class="field_container">Confirm Password:</label>
<input type='password' name='cust_password2' id='confirmpassword'  maxlength="12" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />







</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <INPUT class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" >
</fieldset>  
</form>

</div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


</div> 

<div id="div1">
</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

register_process.php is as follows

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once("config.php");
require_once("all_functions.php");
$cust_firstname = stripslashes($_POST['cust_firstname']);
$cust_lastname = stripslashes($_POST['cust_lastname']);
$cust_sex = stripslashes($_POST['cust_sex']);
$cust_email = stripslashes($_POST['cust_email']);
$cust_password = stripslashes($_POST['cust_password']);
$cust_password2 = stripslashes($_POST['cust_password2']);



$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE cust_email = '$cust_email'");
if (mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
    {
    echo 'That email is already registered';
    exit;
    }
mysql_query("INSERT INTO register (`cust_firstname`,`cust_lastname`, `cust_sex`, `cust_email`, `cust_password`) 
VALUES
('$cust_firstname', '$cust_lastname', '$cust_sex', '$cust_email', '$cust_password')");
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = $cust_email;
    header("Location: http://tripneat.com/");
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: You either need to reload the page or get  all the HTML you want to display when someone is logged in via AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the input type as button and submit the form using javascript .Here is the edited code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <link href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




    <script>

        function submit()  // changesmade
          {
          var str = $("#ajax-contact-form").serialize();
             $.ajax(
             {
             type: "POST",
             url:"register_process.php",
             data: str,
             success:function(result)
                    {
                    $("#div1").html(result);
                    }
              });

              }
    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SIGN UP</a>

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

    <div id="contact_form">  
    <form id="ajax-contact-form" name="contact" action=""> 
    <fieldset>
        <div class="field_container">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cust_firstname" id="firstname"  maxlength="50" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />



    <div class="field_container">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cust_lastname" id="lastname" maxlength="50" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />


    <div class="sex_check" >
    <input type="radio" name="cust_sex" type="radio" value="M" /> Male
    <input type="radio" name="cust_sex" type="radio" value="F" /> Female


    <hr class="line_break">

    <div class="field_container">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cust_email" id="email"  maxlength="100" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />



    <div class="field_container">Password:</label>
    <input type='password' name='cust_password' id='password'  maxlength="12" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />



    <div class="field_container">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type='password' name='cust_password2' id='confirmpassword'  maxlength="12" style="width: 250px; height: 30px"; />







    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <INPUT class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="submit" value="Register" onclick="submit()"/> // changes made
    </fieldset>  
    </form>

    </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->


    </div> 

    <div id="div1">
    </div> 


    </body>
    </html>
```